# constraints structure in the container class

Tags: flutter

Friends, I could not use the constraints structure in the container class. Now, according to my text child, while waiting for the min, max values   to be formed, I always output maxwidth, maxheight values, even if the text content is little. As expected in the training video I watched, it grows according to the max value given according to the text content. but I could not.my code and quit:

```
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Text(
            "Merhaba",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 25),
          ),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: 300.0,
              maxWidth: 200.0,
              minWidth: 150.0,
              minHeight: 150.0)
      ),
    ),
```

Text size is 25, the result is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHNTG.png

I tried font size as 250, the result is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5qWK.png

Comment: Please type code. Screenshot is not efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I edited.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the font size of the text. Now it is 25. Please set bigger values than 25 to see what you expected.

Comment: No, font size is 5,25 even 250, it is same result. When I tried it as 250, only the first letter appears. As it appears: https://i.ibb.co/pX8DwV9/10-20-20-18-2753.png